# React Native - Value '3130049174' doesn't fit into a 32 bit signed int

Tags: java, android, react-native, int, native

I am trying to call an API by passing through a few values in the URL - this works fine on iOS but break on Android.

e.g. `api/v1/betslip/6/113672/669203/149/3130049174?product_id=5`

The value `3130049174` causes the error:

[image]

The error is triggered from line 54 in https://github.com/mhallcouk/stopwatch/blob/master/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/xreact/jni/ReadableNativeMap.cpp

So it is failing at `integer != javaint`

Here is the full code:

```
getBetslipApi(settingsObj, 113672, 669203, 149, 3130049174)



export function getBetslipApi(settings, eventID, marketID, rsID, partnerID) {
//THE RSID IS THE VALUE CAUSING THE ERROR - 3130049174

const url = settings.api+"v1/betslip/"+settings.sport_id+"/"+eventID+"/"+marketID+"/"+partnerID+"/"+rsID+"?product_id="+settings.product_id;


return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getBetslip());
    axios.get(url, {
        headers: {'Cache-Control': 'max-age='+settings.api_cache_time},
        timeout: settings.api_timeout
    })
       //THIS DOES NOT TRIGGER
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            if(data.success) {
                const url = data.data.betslip
                Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
                    if (!supported) {
                        console.log('Error opening external URL: ' + url);
                        return Linking.openURL(url);
                    } else {
                        return Linking.openURL(url);
                    }
                }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
                dispatch(getBetslipSuccess(data.data))
            }else {
                apiError(data, url);
                dispatch(getBetslipFailure(data));
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            apiError(error, url);
            dispatch(getBetslipFailure(error));
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3,130,049,174 is too large for a signed 32-bit integer. The [maximum value for a signed integer in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is 2,147,483,647 (2^31 -1).

Comment: You got it first :D

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a 32 bit signed integer that means it has a minimum value of 2^-31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1

3130049174 is a number outside the range that's why it's causing this problem. You can either use a `double` or `Integer` wrapper class to avoid this issue.